# Why won't Facebook let my dad see pictures of his grandchildren?

Tags: facebook

How can my dad log into Facebook if his account is locked? My dad tried to log into Facebook and it said his account is locked due to suspicious activity. It asked him to verify his date of birth, which he did, but then it just took him back to the same screen of options to verify DOB plus now the choice to upload an ID. He tried multiple times to verify his DOB but it keeps taking him back to the options. He doesn't have a scanner so he can't upload an ID. How can he get into Facebook to see pictures of his grandchildren?

Comment: Places don't always need a scanned ID. A photo will suffice in most cases. Just use your phone and email it to yourself. You could also try a neighbor. Your local library might also have a scanner you could use.

Answer (score 2):

If Facebook is asking for ID, then submit an ID. There are no other ways to verify the account. Facebook is very strict now days for their policies. And if you keep trying other ways other than what they are asking, they can block your account permanently. It is all for our security, better to follow them.

Not having a scanner is not a problem, there are several scanner apps available for phones, or you can use your mobile camera to click the picture of ID and send it to Facebook or you can convert it to PDF using an online converter if Facebook wants it in PDF format.

Comment: He doesn't have a smartphone. He still uses a flip phone.

Comment: @Chloe : That should not be an issue, you can use your phone or someone else's phone.

Comment: I don't live with him. I told him to use someone else's phone to take a photo of his ID but he said it wasn't worth the trouble.